# getting syntax error in insert statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

The following Insert statement is throwing syntax error but I am not finding it.

```
INSERT INTO Test ( [ID] ,[IDType] ,[IDLanguage] ,[State] ,[StateSEO] ,[Permalink] ,[PermalinkMapping] ,[DateCreated] ,[DateModified] ,[SEOName]) 

VALUES 
( 19988 ,72 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,'' ,'' , GETDATE() , GETDATE() ,'H_KDA1559_ST_004' )
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting error "syntax error near ','"

Comment: @user160820 show your table schema?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9a6c/2

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but is it possible that you are using a Management Studio Query Window to execute this, and you happen to have part, but not all, of the query selected when you try to execute it?  That would cause this error.