# SQL syntax error 170 in insert statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

here is my SQL statement and I am getting `Error 170 Incorrect syntax near ',' at line 4`

```
INSERT INTO SEO_Permalink_Test 
( IDObjekt ,IDType ,IDLanguage ,StateSEOName ,StateSEOPermalink ,DatumErstellungSEOName ,DatumLetzteAenderungSEOName ,SEOName)
 VALUES 
 ( 19988 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 , GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_KDA1559_ST_004' ), 
 ( 19989 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 , GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_KDA1559_FS_003' ) , 
 ( 19997 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 , GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_CAU0171_WO_015' ) , 
 ( 19998 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_KDA1559_ST_003' ) , 
 ( 19999 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_KDA1559_FS_001' ) , 
 ( 20001 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_ILI0758_AU_007' ) , 
 ( 20002 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_ILI0758_PO_011' ) , 
 ( 20003 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_ILI0758_RS_008' ) , 
 ( 20004 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_CIT0550_WO_002' ) , 
 ( 20005 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_CIT0550_WO_003' ) , 
 ( 20006 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_CIT0550_TR_001' ) , 
 ( 20007 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_CIT0550_RS_001' ) , 
 ( 20008 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 ,  GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_CSL0152_AU_001' )
```

Comment: which version sql server that you use? I copy your code and it's work in SQL Server 2008

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Multiple `VALUES` was only added in 2008.

Comment: See [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/02/sql-server-2008-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-row-constructor/) for more detail..

Comment: Why have you reposted your question? [getting syntax error in insert statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17490539)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that it is SQL Server 2005 or below

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

SQL Server 2008 introduces the Transact-SQL row constructor (also called a table  value constructor) to specify **multiple rows in a
single INSERT statement**. The row  constructor consists of a single
VALUES clause with multiple value lists enclosed in  parentheses and
separated by a comma. For more information, see Table Value
Constructor  (Transact-SQL).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform a multi-row insert into SQL Server prior than 2008.
You have two ways to do it:

```
INSERT INTO SEO_Permalink_Test 
( IDObjekt ,IDType ,IDLanguage ,StateSEOName ,StateSEOPermalink ,DatumErstellungSEOName ,DatumLetzteAenderungSEOName ,SEOName)
 SELECT 19988 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 , GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_KDA1559_ST_004' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 19989 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 , GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_KDA1559_FS_003' 
...
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO SEO_Permalink_Test 
( IDObjekt ,IDType ,IDLanguage ,StateSEOName ,StateSEOPermalink ,DatumErstellungSEOName ,DatumLetzteAenderungSEOName ,SEOName)
 VALUES 
 ( 19988 , 72 , 1 , 0 , 0 , GETDATE() , GETDATE() , 'H_KDA1559_ST_004' )

INSERT INTO SEO_Permalink_Test 
( IDObjekt ,IDType ,IDLanguage ,StateSEOName ,StateSEOPermalink ,DatumErstellungSEOName ,DatumLetzteAenderungSEOName ,SEOName)
 VALUES 
 ( 19989 ,
```

I would go with the 1st way as it's less verbose.

Comment: Actually this is called "*Row Construction*", as `BULK INSERT` is an explicit command in T-SQL for importing a file, and thus a completely different thing.

Comment: I accept your comment but note that i used the "bulk insert" term not in a specific way or as a command, rather than as a descriptive term to perform a multi-row (bulk, in english) insert.

Comment: I agree with @RBarryYoung - using a term like Bulk Insert, when that is a *specific* term for a different feature of the *same* product is at best misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Just a syntax problem:  you need to have a separate insert statement for each record.

Another alternative, which may add to readability, is to structure the statement like the following

```
 INSERT INTO TableName(col1, col2, col3)
         SELECT( a, b, c) 
   UNION SELECT( d, e, f) 
   UNION SELECT( g, h, i)
```

Comment: Please add the "ALL" keyword to "UNION" to avoid unnecessary overhead

Answer (score 0):

your insert statement is parsed in my sql error free.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
    VALUES ('First',1),
    ('Second',2),
    ('Third',3),
    ('Fourth',4),
    ('Fifth',5)
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/02/sql-server-2008-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-row-constructor/